# Filemaker XSL - if node contains specific text - just will not work

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement, contains, filemaker

I have an XML file like this:

```
<propertys>
 <property>
  <ref>12345</ref>
  <description>Lovely house with swimming pool.</description>
 </property>
 <property>
  <ref>54321</ref>
  <description>Lovely house with outbuildings and lake.</description>
 </property>
 <property>
  <ref>67890</ref>
  <description>Lovely house with garage and further parking.</description>
 </property>
</propertys>
```

I have a number of output fields such as Lake, Garage, Swimming Pool, Parking and others.

When I import this XML into Filemaker using XSL, I want to check if the description node contains the word 'pool' and then set the corresponding output field as Yes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
  <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
  <PRODUCT BUILD="" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 12.0v4"/>
  <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="" LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="" TIMEFORMAT=""/>
  <METADATA>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Ref" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="SwimmingPool" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Garage" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Parking" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Lake" TYPE="TEXT" />       
  </METADATA>

  <RESULTSET FOUND="">
   <xsl:for-each select="propertys/property">
      <ROW RECORDID="" MODID="">

        <!-- REF -->
        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="ref"/></DATA></COL>

        <COL><DATA>
        <xsl:if test="contains(description,'pool')">
        Yes
        </xsl:if>
        </DATA></COL>

        <COL><DATA>
        <xsl:if test="contains(description,'garage')">
        Yes
        </xsl:if>
        </DATA></COL>

        <COL><DATA>
        <xsl:if test="contains(description,'parking')">
        Yes
        </xsl:if>
        </DATA></COL>

        <COL><DATA>
        <xsl:if test="contains(description,'lake')">
        Yes
        </xsl:if>
        </DATA></COL>

     </ROW>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

I have tried every which way, including applying templates, and I cannot get this to work yet it all seems fine from having spent hours Googling and Googling.

When the data comes into Filemaker, the Swimming Pool and other fields are blank.

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the data comes into Filemaker, the Swimming Pool and other fields
>   are blank.

No, they are not blank. They contain (when the condition is satisfied) the string:

```
         Yes
```

because that is the string you have specified as the result of the `<xsl:if>` statement. Try instead:

```
<xsl:if test="contains(description,'pool')">Yes</xsl:if>
```

or:

```
<xsl:if test="contains(description,'pool')">
    <xsl:text>Yes</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand what is different about your examples than my code? When I say blank, the data is not getting through to Filemaker. It should be Yes for when XSL finds the words pool or lake or whatever, but even though the code seems fine there is no 'Yes' ending up in my Filemaker. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh I see now. I missed out the <XSL:text> part. It seems to work now - many thanks indeed!

Comment: "*When I say blank, the data is not getting through to Filemaker.*" It is, but you need to either click into the field or make the field taller in order to see it.